# Deploying Django project on pythonanywhere: Error running WSGI application

Tags: mysql, deployment, pythonanywhere

I have a mysql database for my django project. Had also installed XAMPP for local development. While deploying I did. I think there's a problem with the python version of my pthonanywhere bash console. My project can support only python 3.7 because of the kiteconnect module that I am using.
I have installed kiteconnect, mysqlclient, and mysql connector (checked it with pip3 freeze too)

```
pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python = 3.7 <git-repo-url>
```

I set up my database and made the changes suggested in my settings.py file in DATABASE, (changed hostname, database name, passowrd, PORT:3306, etc). I am getting this error in logs:

```
Error running WSGI application
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Please help me. This is a project I'm working on. Will be happy to provide further inputs too.

Answer (score 0):

pa_autoconfigure_django creates a virtualenv using the requirements.txt file in your project. If you do not have mysqlclient in your requirements.txt file, then it will not be installed in the virtualenv.